# Error: The loader "C:/Users/........./proyecto.component.css" didn't return a string al querer compilar proyecto en Angular

Tags: css, nodejs, angular

Estoy teniendo un problema para compilar el proyecto desde vsc. El problema empezó cuando comencé a trabajar junto con el backend.
El error que me tira es el siguiente:

```
Error: The loader "C:/Users/........./proyecto.component.css" didn't return a string.


Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\..........node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fws&logging=info&reconnect=10' in 'C:\Users\.........
```

Busqué información en varios lugares, probé varias cosas, pero no puedo solucionarlo.

Comment: en tu `package.lock.json` ya buscaste si tienes la dependencia webpack?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si la tengo

Comment: ok, entonces intenta borrando la carpeta node modules, luego borrar tu cache de npm con `npm cache clean --force` y finalmente haz un `npm install` (asumiendo que usas npm para tu gestion de dependencias)